# Set dropdown select option with a default value as page loads

Tags: angular

Below is my code. I want the "Select the type of document" to display as the form loads initially. Thus I set the first  to that and the second  is fetching date from my backend. [Dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iLp8.png)

```
<select class="custom-select" name="documentType" [(ngModel)]="myDocument.documentType.id"
                       #documentType="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'alert-border': documentType.errors?.emptyField}">
                 <option value="0" >Select the type of document</option>
                 <option [value]="documentType.id" *ngFor="let documentType of docTypes">{{documentType.denomination}}</option>
               </select>
```

I have tried:

```
<option value="0" selected= "selected">Select the type of document</option>
```

No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could set in TS file:

```
myDocument.documentType.id = "defaultValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

change ngModel attribute to [(ngModel)]="selectedDocumentTypeId"

```
<select class="custom-select" name="documentType" [(ngModel)]="selectedDocumentTypeId"
   #documentType="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'alert-border': documentType.errors?.emptyField}">
     <option value="0" >Select the type of document</option>
     <option [value]="documentType.id" *ngFor="let documentType of docTypes">{{documentType.denomination}}</option>
</select>
```

In your ts file

```
selectedDocumentTypeId: string = '';

ngOnInit() { 
  this.selectedDocumentTypeId  = docTypes[0].id; /* Hoping docTypes array exist before this statement*/
}
```

Comment: this.selectedDocumentTypeId  = docTypes[0].id;  says type number is not assignable to type string.

Comment: Change it to selectedDocumentTypeId: number = '';

Answer (score 0):

```
<option [ngValue]="0">Select the type of document</option>
```

*Make sure init value of `myDocument.documentType.id` is `0` .

Comment: It works for me. In addition, I had to set from the back end not to accept a zero id. Thank you Karmidzhanov